# Differential Equation: $y'=ty+1$ , $y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For

$y'=ty+1$, $y(0)=0$

determine $w(n)$ for an arbitrary value of $n$. (Picard's iteration method).

I found a solution, but not sure if it true or not.

$$w(n) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2n - 1}}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdots (2n - 1)}$$

Need some help.

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Comment: I have shared in the question(Edited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First write out the associated integral equation:

$$y(t)=\int_0^t(sy(s)+1)ds.$$

The first step in the iteration is $y_0(t)=y_0=0$, so $y_1(t)=\int_0^t(s\cdot 0+1)ds=t.$ Continuing in this manner, the first few terms are:

$$y_0(t)=0$$
$$y_1(t)=t$$
$$y_2(t)=t+\frac{t^3}{3}$$
$$y_3(t)=t+\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{t^5}{3\cdot5}$$

From here it's probably easy enough to guess the general form of the $n$th term that you already noticed, $$y_n(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{t^{2k-1}}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2k-1)}.$$ We can prove that this is correct by induction.

$$y_{n+1}=\int_0^t(1+s\cdot y_n(s))ds$$
$$=\int_0^t(1+s\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{s^{2k-1}}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2k-1)})ds$$
$$=t+\int_0^t(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{s^{2k}}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2k-1)})ds$$
$$=t+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{t^{2k+1}}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2k-1)(2k+1)}$$
$$=t+\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{t^{2k-1}}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2k-1)}$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{t^{2k-1}}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2k-1)},$$

which is the correct form we were looking for.